# Get browser console to show filename + line number in javascript file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firefox, browser

a tricky question to word. I'm new to React and have been debugging my code using console logs in Firefox.

However, at times the Firefox console window stops showing the filename and line number of the console log and displays a different format. I can click on it to inspect it in Firefox's debugger but I'd prefer to change it to the standard filename:line number view. Anyone know how to do this?

I'd prefer to keep it like this:

[image]

And not like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Still unsure as to why this happens - but the quick solution is to restart npm via command line. Browser's command line then resumes the form of the first image above.

```
npm start
```